# Boost asio receive specified size of data

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

To receive asynchronously data from socket i use `async_read_some`, but this function receives  not all data sometimes, what function i should use to read asynchronously for example 10 bytes and this function should callback only when these 10 bytes will be readed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async_read_some` has a counterpart `async_read`, which will only complete once the full size has been read.